# Angular Router reload everything everytime a route change

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have worked in many Angular projects and never saw an issue like this. I'm using Angular version 16.

This is my routing:

```js
export const routing = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    canActivate: [() => inject(CoreGuard).canActivate()],
    canActivateChild: [(snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => inject(AccountGuard).canActivateChild(snapshot, state)],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
        title: 'Home',
      },
      {
        path: 'permission',
        component: PermissionComponent,
        title: 'Permission',
      },

      // Chat
      {
        path: 'chat',
        loadChildren: () => import('../module/chat/chat.module').then(m => m.ChatModule),
      },

      // Apps
      {
        path: 'apps',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'engine',
            loadChildren: () => import('../module/apps/engine/engine.module').then(m => m.EngineModule),
          }
        ],
      },

      // Catalog
      {
        path: 'catalog',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'tag',
            loadChildren: () => import('../module/catalog/tag/tag.module').then(m => m.TagModule),
          },
          {
            path: 'product',
            loadChildren: () => import('../module/catalog/product/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule),
          },
        ],
      },

      // Store
      {
        path: 'store',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'config',
            loadChildren: () => import('../module/store/config/config.module').then(m => m.ConfigModule),
          },
          {
            path: 'page',
            loadChildren: () => import('../module/store/page/page.module').then(m => m.PageModule),
          },
        ],
      },

      // Coming Soon
      {
        path: '**',
        component: ComingSoonComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Basically what's happening is that everytime I access any existing routing, I can see the main app blinking and the data is being loaded again.

For example, I have a `console.log()` on the file `AppComponent->Constructor()` that is logging each time there is a navigation, no matter what navigation it is. Also, if I have a children module route that also have children, the parent is being executed multiple times.

For example:

```js
export const chatRouting: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ChatListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ChatEmptyComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ChatEmptyComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

The above routing is the `ChatModule` routing, where the component `ChatListComponent` will load all chat instances that exists and then it will navigate to an specific chat to open within `ChatListComponent`.

However for every navigation to a chat instance, not only it will load the whole app routing, it will also call the api within `ChatListComponent` again.

I have no idea what's going on here. I've done this way many many times and never had this issue.

Comment: I am not sure about you exact issue but is there any issue related to changeDetection in you component? try to set ChangeDetection.OnPush in parent component & child component

Comment: Are you using `routerlink` in your "<a>" tags? see that, in Angular, you **not** use `href`, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#defining-a-basic-route)

Comment: Try to comment 'canActivate' & 'canActivateChild' guard & check.